# Target class [MyMiddleware] does not exist

Tags: laravel, middleware

Estoy probando un proyecto nuevo con Laravel 9. He creado un *middleware* con el comando `php artisan make:middleware MyMiddleware`. El *middleware* se crea correctamente, con el código base.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MyMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Después lo registro en `app/Http/Kernel.php`. En la matriz `protected $middleware` añado la entrada `\App\Http\Middleware\MyMiddleware::class,`. En la matriz `protected $routeMiddleware` añado la entrada `'mymiddleware' => \App\Http\Middleware\MyMiddleware::class,`.

Sin embargo, cuando voy a ejecutar mi página me salta el error

> Target class [MyMiddleware] does not exist.

¿Por qué? ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: ¿En qué archivo PHP aparece ese error y en qué línea? Eso te dará una pista de por dónde empezar.

Comment: Posiblemente la lista de routes esté en caché. Lo que conviene hacer es: `php artisan optimize`